# Electron-React: MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 21 updateDeviceList listeners added to [EventEmitter]

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, electron

I tried searching all over in understanding the cause of this,
and i think i have the tip of the string,
i use usb detection do detect when usb devices are connected,

```
usbDetect.on('add', () => sendDeviceListToGUI(1));
```

within this function i do the following

```
const sendDeviceListToGUI= async (status: number) => {
  mainWindow?.webContents.send('updatingDeviceList', status);
  const list = await getConnectedDeviceArray();
  mainWindow?.webContents.send('updateDeviceList', list);
};
```

i assume that the event pile up whenever a device is connected or disconnected,

```
(node:41276) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 21 updateDeviceList listeners added to [EventEmitter]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use `TestApp --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:41276) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 21 updatingDeviceList listeners added to [EventEmitter]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

i tried increasing the limit but with no luck, i feel that i need to resolve the event like with promises.

(also the --trace-warnings ... doesn't work any idea why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, i have this call in my react file, since i use functional components every time i rerender the component, it registers a new listener.

```
window.myapiAPI.updateDeviceList()
```

i think there is an option to solve it with hooks, and make sure the hook runs once.
but for now in my preload file i remove all listeners before assigning a new one.

```
ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('updateDeviceList');
```

### UPDATE 2

i wrapped all the functions in a useEffect hook that runs on the first render.

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.myAPI.message((message: string) => {
      AppToaster.show({
        message,
        intent: Intent.WARNING,
      });
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: I think you should combine 2 solution. First, only call add listener when needed. Remove when it done his task. The common way is listen when Component mount and dispose when component unmount

Answer (score 0):

You can register the ipc listener using an useEffect hook, *without* dependencies to run it only when mounting. Use the [useEffect cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) function to remove the listener again when unmounting the component, as suggested by Hồng Phúc.

Using your example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  window.myAPI.message((message: string) => {
    AppToaster.show({
      message,
      intent: Intent.WARNING,
    });
  });
  return function cleanup() {
    ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('updateDeviceList');
  }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error basically shows up warn you that, your app will be running slow from the moment the "Max listeners exceeded Warning" appears. No use using the setMaxListeners() to increase limit. Even to do this, is just painful as the error will keep appearing.

The simple way around this problem is to reduce the number of times and event emitter is used. It shouldn't be more than 10. This is so to improve code readability and improve performance.

In electron, the send() method is used in place of emit() which is used in other nodejs frameworks like expressjs and nextjs. Check the number of times this is used. That's all.